# jQuery UI draggable not bound to parent bounds

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have created a js-based node editor. I have a div element I use as a parent for the nodes. Although I define the containment to parent you can move the nodes outside of the parents bounds. You can not move it lower than the last document element though.
[image]

The important html code is:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendData(fetchData())">Send data</button>
    <div id="node-container" class="node-container" style="height: 500px; width: 90%">
        <svg id="svg"/>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendData(fetchData())">Send data</button>
```

And the js for the draggable is:

```
$(this.domElement).draggable({
    containment: 'parent',
    cancel: '.connection,.output,.data',
    drag: function(event, ui){
        that.updatePosition();
    }
});
```

Maybe I did something wrong with the parenting so here it is as well:

```
this.domElement = document.createElement('div');
document.getElementById('node-container').appendChild(this.domElement);
```

I haven't worked with JavaScript too much and am still learning!

EDIT: Here is the definition of the node-container:

```
<div id="node-container" class="node-container" style="height: 500px; width: 90%">
</div>
```

Complete StoryNode.js:
https://hastebin.com/kiyoyekoce.js

```js
// ===================================================================
// Node class. Represents a javascript version of the java Node class
// ===================================================================

var nodes = []; //Have second reduced node version running, maybe as a method in the Node? Call simple for loop in web-link

function StoryNode(name) {
    this.name = name;

    let that = this;

    nodes.push(this);

    // Add our graphical representation

    this.domElement = document.createElement('div');
    document.getElementById('node-container').appendChild(this.domElement);

    this.domElement.classList.add('node');
    this.domElement.classList.add('container-fixed');
    this.domElement.setAttribute('title', name.replace("Node",""));

    let remDom = document.createElement('div');
    remDom.classList.add('delete-node');
    remDom.innerHTML ='<i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"/>';
    this.domElement.appendChild(remDom);

    remDom.onclick = function (e) {

        that.detachAll();

        for( let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
            if ( nodes[i] === that) {
                nodes.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }

        that.domElement.parentElement.removeChild(that.domElement);
    };

    // Add the node body

    // Directories
    var innerDomGroup = document.createElement('div');
    innerDomGroup.classList.add('row');
    this.domElement.appendChild(innerDomGroup);

    // Outputs
    this.outputDomGroup = document.createElement('div');
    this.outputDomGroup.classList.add('col-fixed-small-1');
    innerDomGroup.appendChild(this.outputDomGroup);

    // Inner Data
    this.dataDomGroup = document.createElement('div');
    this.dataDomGroup.classList.add('col-fixed-medium-1');
    innerDomGroup.appendChild(this.dataDomGroup);

    // Inputs
    this.inputDomGroup = document.createElement('div');
    this.inputDomGroup.classList.add('col-fixed-small-1');
    innerDomGroup.appendChild(this.inputDomGroup);


    //Node data
    this.inputs = [];
    this.data = [];
    this.outputs = [];
}

StoryNode.prototype.addInput = function(name, inputType){
    let input = new NodeInput(name, inputType);
    input.node = this;
    this.inputs.push(input);
    this.inputDomGroup.appendChild(input.domElement);

    return input;
};

StoryNode.prototype.addOutput = function(name, outputType){
    let output = new NodeOutput(name, outputType);
    output.node = this;
    this.outputs.push(output);
    this.outputDomGroup.appendChild(output.domElement);

    return output;
};

StoryNode.prototype.addData = function(name, outputType){
    let data = new NodeData(name, outputType);
    data.node = this;
    this.data.push(data);
    this.dataDomGroup.appendChild(data.domElement);

    return data;
};

StoryNode.prototype.ownsInput = function(input){
    for(let i = 0; i < this.inputs.length; i++){
        if(this.inputs[i] === input)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
};

Node.prototype.ownsOutput = function(output){
    for(let i = 0; i < this.outputs.length; i++){
        if(this.outputs[i] === output)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
};

StoryNode.prototype.detachAll = function(output){
    for(let item of this.inputs){
        if(item.output)
            item.output.detachInput();
    }

    for(let item of this.outputs){
        if(item.input)
            item.detachInput();
    }
};

StoryNode.prototype.updatePosition = function(){

    for(let j = 0; j < this.outputs.length; j++){
        if(this.outputs[j].input != null){
            let oP = this.outputs[j].getOutputPoint();
            let iP = this.outputs[j].input.getAttachPoint();

            let pStr = this.createPath(iP, oP);
            this.outputs[j].input.path.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', pStr);
        }
    }

    for(let j = 0; j < this.inputs.length; j++){
        if(this.inputs[j].output != null){
            let iP = this.inputs[j].getAttachPoint();
            let oP = this.inputs[j].output.getOutputPoint();

            let pStr = this.createPath(iP, oP);
            this.inputs[j].path.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', pStr);
        }
    }
};

StoryNode.prototype.createPath = function(a, b){
    let diff = {
        x: b.x - a.x,
        y: b.y - a.y
    };

    let pathStr = 'M' + a.x + ',' + a.y + ' ';
    pathStr += 'C';
    pathStr += a.x + diff.x / 3 * 2 + ',' + a.y + ' ';
    pathStr += a.x + diff.x / 3 + ',' + b.y + ' ';
    pathStr += b.x + ',' + b.y;

    return pathStr;
};

StoryNode.prototype.moveTo = function(point){
    this.domElement.style.top = point.y + 'px';
    this.domElement.style.left = point.x + 'px';
    this.updatePosition();
};

StoryNode.prototype.initUI = function(){
    let that = this;
    // Make draggable
    // noinspection JSValidateTypes
    $(this.domElement).draggable({
        containment: 'parent',
        cancel: '.connection,.output,.data',
        drag: function(event, ui){
            that.updatePosition();
        }
    });

    //Mak node design smaller as it holds no data inputs
    if(this.data.length === 0) {
        this.domElement.classList.remove('container-fixed');
        this.domElement.classList.add('container-fixed-min');

        this.dataDomGroup.classList.remove('col-fixed-medium-1');
        this.dataDomGroup.classList.add('col-fixed-medium-1-min');
    }

    // Fix positioning
    this.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';

    document.body.appendChild(this.domElement);
    // Update Visual
    this.updatePosition();
};

// Node 1
let node = new StoryNode('Page');


// Move to initial positions
node.moveTo({x: 150, y: 20});

// Connect Nodes


// Add to DOM
node.initUI();
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #101010;
    color: #d4d4d4;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.node:before{
    content:attr(title) " ";
    display: block;
    border-top-left-radius:.75em;
    border-top-right-radius:.75em;
    background-color:#6e6e6e;
    padding:0.1em .3em 0em;
    margin:-.1em -.3em 0.2em;
}
.node{
    background-color: #4e4e4e;
    border-radius: .75em;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0.1em .3em .25em;
    position:absolute;
    cursor: move;
}
.connection:after{
    position:absolute;
    border:solid 1px #dedede;
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    width:0.5em;
    height:0.5em;
    border-radius:0.5em;

}

.delete-node{
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;

    position:absolute;
    color: #b8b8b8;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius:0.5em;
    width:22px;
    height:22px;

    cursor: default;

    top: 3px;
    right: 8px;
}

.connection.filled:after{
    border:solid 1px transparent;
}
.connection:hover:after{
    border-color:red;
}
.output{
    left: .1em;
    top:.1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.input{
    left: 2em;
    top: .1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.connection{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    padding-right:0.5em;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.connection:after{
    content:"";
    right:0em;
    top:0.25em;
}

.filled-node:after{
    background-color: #d4d9de;
}
.empty-node:after{
    border: 2px solid #d4d9de;
}

.filled-boolean:after{
    background-color: #4f8fde;
}
.empty-boolean:after{
    border: 2px solid #4f8fde;
}


svg{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-100;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}

/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.round-edge {
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.container-fixed {
    width: 200px !important;
}

.container-fixed-min {
    width: 100px !important;
}

.col-fixed-small-1 {
    width: 5px;
}

.col-fixed-small-2 {
    width: 5px;
}
.col-fixed-medium-1 {
    width: 180px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: -12px;
}

.col-fixed-medium-1-min {
    width: 80px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: -12px;
}

.node-container {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="node-container" class="node-container">
    <svg id="svg"/>
</div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send data</button>
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Twisty this is almost all you need to recreate this. Just missing the CSS and I don't think you want 100 lines code copied, right? What do you need that isn't there?

Comment: It is not clear how I verify this example. What is `that`? Where is `this.domElement` defined? Where is this appended to the document in relationship to initialization of draggable.

Comment: Ok that is this. This is in this case my node class object. The dom element is defined in the constructor while the draggable is in a method called init ui which is called from the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is when you append the element. If it's not appended when you initialize draggable, it may not understand the `parent` relationship.

Consider the following example:

```js
$(function() {
  function addNode(title, content, tObj) {
    if (title == undefined) {
      title = "New Node";
    }
    if (content == undefined) {
      content = "<p></p>";
    }
    if (tObj == undefined) {
      tObj = $("#node-container");
    }
    var node = $("<div>", {
      class: "node-element"
    }).appendTo(tObj);

    $("<div>", {
      class: "node-title"
    }).html(title).appendTo(node);

    $("<span>", {
      class: "btn btn-delete-node"
    }).html("x").click(function() {
      var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this node?");
      if (r) {
        $(this).closest(".node-element").remove();
      }
    }).appendTo($(".node-title", node));

    $("<div>", {
      class: "node-content"
    }).html(content).appendTo(node);

    node.draggable({
      containment: 'parent',
      handle: ".node-title",
      cancel: '.connection,.output,.data',
      stop: function(e, ui) {
        // update position
      }
    });
  }
  $(".add-node-btn").click(function() {
    addNode();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: "arial", san-seriff;
}

.node-container {
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
}

.btn-primary {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
  color: #FFF;
}

.node-container .node-element {
  background-color: #212121;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 0;
  width: 125px;
  height: 75px;
}

.node-container .node-element .node-title {
  background-color: #484848;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  border: 0;
  min-height: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.node-container .node-element .node-title .btn-delete-node {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send data</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-node-btn">Add Node</button>
<div id="node-container" class="node-container" style="height: 500px; width: 90%">
  <svg id="svg" />
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send data</button>
```

Since your example code is not a Minimal, Complete, or Verifiable example, it's difficult to determine when or how your elements are added versus initialized.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So the exact creation flow I have is:
Instantiate via constructor (add to parent),
Add Inputs via add method,
Add Outputs via add method,
Add Values via add method,
Call Node#initUI which does the draggable and and some formatting things depending on values

Comment: You think any css could cause the issue? I can send that in if needed. I didn't want to paste too much code as well. I can add some more code if needed though.

Comment: @Gerolmed unlikely a css issue but possible. Any errors appear in console? If you're adding everything (to the Dom) and then initiating draggable, it should understand the present. Can you examine the resulting elements and ensure the structure is as expected?

Comment: Sorry for me not answering had stuff to do. There are no errors in the console, but somehow the nodes aren't parented to the node-container element.
Am I doing something wrong with the parenting? The parenting code is already shown above, I will add the html element as well.

Comment: I added my node.js script to the post. Maybe that will help. I originally had it named Node, but now changed the name to StoryNode. I did some logging and the parent object exists and is found and this.domElement is not null!

Comment: @Gerolmed your link, https://hastebin.com/kiyoyekoce.js, did not show anything. Again, it would be best to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve as it's too hard to determine what you're seeing.

Comment: Added the mcve as you asked. Its a bit long and I tried removing most of the unneeded code. Most of the actual initialisation code is done by Tymeleaf and the Inputs, Outputs as wll as Data is in different classes.

Comment: I hope that thats enough, so you can help me :)